# How can I write this Clojure macro more idiomatically?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp, lisp-macros

```
(defmacro get-color [color-name]
  `@(thi.ng.color.core/as-int32 (var-get (resolve (symbol "thi.ng.color.core"
                                            (str '~color-name))))))
```

I like to avoid using the `(var-get (resolve (symbol ... (str '~parem))))`. Something like `thi.ng.color.core/(~color-name)`.

(I am using this macro in a very small personal project, and I don't care if it's really bad practice to create a macro for this use case. Though I like knowing why it would be problematic in bigger projects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```clj
(require 'thi.ng.color.core)

(defmacro get-color
  [color-name]
  (let [sym (symbol "thi.ng.color.core"
                    (str color-name))]
    `@(thi.ng.color.core/as-int32 ~sym)))

(comment
  (get-color "RED") ;;=> 4294901760
  (get-color RED) ;;=> 4294901760
  )
```

Comment: My solution works like this `(get-color RED)`. This one doesn't even work with `(get-color 'RED)`.

Comment: You didn't specify your usage. I updated the answer.